# How to Clear an Apps Cache with Tasker

Tags: android, tasker

I'm trying to use Tasker to clear the cache of a specified app (I'm using the Google app at the moment). My setup had been based off of [this old reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/446hyb/clear_cache_action/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share), but I can't seem to get it to work. My Clean Cache task had two actions. The first is Send Intent with the following parameters configured:
Action: android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS

Data: package:com.android.google

Target: Activity

The second action is am auto input which selects the text "Clear Cache".

When I run this the screen looks like it's trying to open an app (the screen slides to black) but quickly returns to Tasker. The first action (send intent) states it has competed successfully and the second action (the auto input) is still running for a bit (it has about a 20 second timeout).  I think the second action is setup correctly because if I run the task and open the Google app settings where you'd clear the cache is cleared. It seems that the send intent is just not bringing me to the right part of the settings so the intent can run.

Comment: Do you have root?

Comment: I didn't at the time.  I've since rooted (but was hoping for a non-root solution)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late but you can try it like this:

```
A1: Run Shell 
[ Command:p="Your Packagename without the quotation marks"; rm -rf /data/data/$p/cache 
Timeout (Seconds):0 Use Root:On Store Output In: Store Errors In: Store Result In: ]
```